# Drawing a scene in xz plane opengl

Tags: c++, opengl

I am working on an opengl program. The viewing parameters are :
eye 0 -4 6
viewup 0 1 0
lookat 0 0 0

I want to draw a background rectangle (with texture) such that I will be able to see it from the current eye location. Right now, the eye is looking from the -ve Y direction. I want to be able to draw a rectangle that covers the entire screen. I am not understanding what coordinates to give to the rectangle and how to get the texture mapping.
Currently I have this in my method:
What would be the code for the same. I have this in function:

```
glPushMatrix();
glLoadIdentity();
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex2f(-1.0, -1.0);
glVertex2f(-1.0, 1.0);
glVertex2f(1.0, 1.0);
glVertex2f(1.0, -1.0);
glEnd();
glPopMatrix();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest option for drawing a background image that is independent of the camera is to draw it in normalized device coordinates (NDC) and do not perform any transformations/projections on it.
To cover the whole screen, you have to draw a quad going from p = [-1, -1] to [1,1]. The texture coordinates can then be found by tex = (p + 1)/2

Normalized device coordinates are the coordinates one would normally get after applying projection and the perspective divide. They span a cube from [-1,-1,-1] to [1,1,1] where the near plane is mapped to z = -1 (at least in OpenGL, in DirectX the near plane is mapped to z=0). In your special case, the depth should not matter, as long as you draw the background plane as the first element in each frame and disable the depth-test.

Comment: Thanks.How do you draw something in NDC? Sorry I am a beginner.

Comment: Simply define vertices with the coordinates [-1,-1],[-1,1],[1,1],[1,-1]. Draw the quad with all matrices set to identity then.

Comment: What would be the code for the same. I have updated question with the code I have currently. @BDL

Comment: The vertices look correct to me, but you have to make sure that the matrix stack is totally empty. glPushMatrix at the beginning indicates to me that there is already something on it. Also ensure that the projection matrix stack does only contain an identity matrix.